# Command prompt output redirection from an application

Tags: c++, command-prompt

I want to run command prompt through an application. I used shell execute for this. Now from cmd, I want to run a .exe file which gives me some output and wants to redirect this output to a text file. Used commands are as follows:

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe",cmdCommand.c_str(), 0, SW_HIDE)
```

Here cmdCommand is -

```
/C "C:\Program Files\Application\some.exe some parameters serverName > C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\output.txt
```

This works fine on my machine but not working on another machine.
On other machines, only blank output.txt is getting created.

Comment: Try running the exe without redirection and check if its running as expected.

Comment: exe works fine on other machine and gives the desired output and works well with redirection also.